# Metasploit crashed after upgrade

Tags: metasploit, kali-linux

I have recently upgraded metasploit framework and after doing it, when I try to launch it I get the next error:

```
msfconsole
Unable to find a spec satisfying metasploit-framework (>= 0) in the set. Perhaps the lockfile is corrupted?
Run bundle install to install missing gems.
```

I have unistalled it and reinstall but the problem continues. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had the same problem, the following fixed it:

```
sudo gem install bundler -v 2.2.4

sudo msfdb reinit
sudo msfconsole
```

Just be aware that the bundler version may have updated since this was posted and therefore may need to be changed. Check what version you're currently running before making these changes.

https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/issues/11597

Comment: Also be aware that bundler will complain about being called with `sudo`. This is due to a problem on macOS which can lead to problems. From my research it seems that *nix OSes are not affected.

Answer (score 0):

What finally worked for me was updating my bundler then running bundle install :

```
/usr/share/metasploit-framework$ sudo gem install bundler:2.2.5
/usr/share/metasploit-framework$ sudo bundle install
```

Comment: That solution don't work in my case :(

Comment: What output do you get when you run bundle install?

Answer (score 0):

happend to me too. but my solution was easier. i didnt touch kali for a while, so i did all the upgrades and therfore i started entering "sudo su". so when i then start msfconsole i get exactly the same error message. enter "exit" to leave root and try again... worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue after doing `sudo apt upgrade`.

To fix that, I had to do `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade -y`.

I got this solution from here https://www.reddit.com/r/Kalilinux/comments/l4zi6i/hey_everyone/